# Vuejs3 props getting undefined from laravel blade to vue component

Tags: laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

here is the blade file

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div id="app">     
  <demo test="fsdf"></demo>  
</div>
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

here is the app.js file

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import Demo from './components/Demo.vue';

const vue3App = createApp(Demo);
vue3App.mount('#app');
```

here is the Demo.vue file

```
<template>
<h1>Demo</h1>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['test'],
    setup(props) {
        console.log(props);
    }
}
</script>
```

The props always showing undefined in the Demo Component!.Don't know what i missed. Also I am using laravel-mix of 6.0.34.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's undefined because you have to regsiter the component first

```
    import {createApp} from 'vue';
    import Demo from './components/Demo.vue';
    
    const app = createApp({
       mounted() {
          console.log('The app is working')
       }
    });
    app.component('demo', Demo); //global registration
    app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: **MohKoma**, I tried but still undefined. Also the component gets rendered into the DOM, Only issue to access the props.

Comment: Hi! I just updated the code, please try again and check the console to confirm that the app is working too.
You should find `The app is working`

Comment: it's working now!!! Thanks  **MohKoma**  you saved my day. But what's the difference between passing component inside createApp()?

Comment: Well, if you pass the component in createApp() it will just bind the component to id="app' element. Therefore the component will be the app enter point. which you have to create many apps incase you have many components.
Therefore, the best way would be to create a single app and attach your components to it. 